# Dzil Release Clobbers Jar File

Tags: perl, perl-module, dist-zilla

I have created a Perl module to provide an interface with the RNG-processing Java library [Jing](https://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/). The code is located [here](https://github.com/byutrg/XML-Jing). I use `[Inline::Java][3]` to compile and load a small class which utilizes `jing.jar`, both located in the `java` directory, which is shared via `[File::ShareDir][4]`. Running `prove -vl` or `dzil test`, the module works perfectly fine, and the tests all pass:

```
>prove -vl
t\0-use.t .............
1..1
ok 1 - use XML::Jing;
ok
t\01-validates_xml.t ..
1..3
ok 1 - successfully reads a valid RNG
ok 2 - returns nothing when XML file is valid
ok 3
ok
t\02-exceptions.t .....
1..5
ok 1 - warning for nonexistent RNG file
ok 2 - constructor returns nothing for non-existent RNG file
ok 3 - warning for bad RNG file
ok 4 - constructor returns nothing for bad RNG file
ok 5 - warning for nonexistent XML file
ok
All tests successful.
Files=3, Tests=9,  6 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.16 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Tests also pass when a distro is built using `dzil build`:

```
dzil build
cd XML-Jing-0.x
perl Build.PL
build
build test
```

However, using `dzil release`, Inline::Java croaks when it tries to load jing.jar. We get these crazy errors below:

```
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/01-validates_xml.t line 5.
t/01-validates_xml.t ..........
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
No subtests run

A problem was encountered while attempting to compile and install your InlineJava code. The command that failed was:
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation  -d "C:\strawberry\cpan\build\XML-Jing-0.01-Skydfp\_Inline\lib\auto\XML\Jing_706b" RNGValidator.java > cmd.out 2>&1

The build directory was:
C:\strawberry\cpan\build\XML-Jing-0.01-Skydfp\_Inline\build\XML\Jing_706b

The error message was:
error: error reading C:\strawberry\cpan\build\XML-Jing-0.01-Skydfp\blib\lib\auto\share\dist\XML-Jing\jing.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
```

Currently I load the jar using a begin block to edit the `CLASSPATH` variable:

```
BEGIN{
    use Env::Path;
    my $classpath = Env::Path->CLASSPATH;
    $classpath->Append(path(dist_dir('XML-Jing'),'jing.jar'));
}
```

Using `jarsigner`, I verified that the jar is corrupted in the build folder created by `dzil release` but not in the one created by `dzil build`:

In the build created via `dzil build`:

```
jarsigner -verify java/jing.jar
jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)
```

In the build created via `dzil release`:

```
jarsigner -verify java/jing.jar
jarsigner: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
```

To summarize, `dzil release` clobbers a jar in my shared directory, while `dzil build` does not. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make this module work properly?

Comment: Since I updated this, it might actually be more of a bug report to Dist::Zilla. In which case, this may just be a reward to @RJBS or someone else for fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug. The kind that happens often and that has happened before in dzil. 

`Dist-Zilla-4.300034\lib\Dist\Zilla\Dist\Builder.pm` line 388

replace `open my $fh, '<', $filename;`  with   `open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename;`

Comment: RJBS and DAGOLDEN fixed dzil encoding problems recently, so it should all be fine now. http://rjbs.manxome.org/rubric/entry/2021

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message "jing.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)" what I can make out is that might be a case that jing.jar is corrupted. I would suggest you to download the jing.jar file again and then try putting it on the CLASS_PATH.
Below is one link from where you can download jing

http://jing-trang.googlecode.com/files/jing-20091111.zip

Thanks

Comment: The jar is indeed corrupted, but only when in the automated build environment. I need to figure out why, and how to make it not be corrupted in the build environment.

Comment: Thank you for bringing to my attention the fact that the released jar is already corrupted. I realized that the problem is something with `dzil release`, not with Perl installation environments or something else.